# how to split the contents when finding the elements

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I'm working on my PHP that I'm using simple_html_dom to find the list of elements that I'm looking for before I could splitting the contents into separate.

Here is the output:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<tv generator-info-name="www.mysite.com/test">
<p id='channels'>101 ABC FAMILY</p>
<p id='channels'>102 CBS</p>
<p id='channels'>103 CNN USA</p>
<p id='channels'>105 ESPN USA</p>
<p id='channels'>106 Fox News</p>
<p id='channels'>107 Animal Planet</p>
```

I want to split the contents into two different variables as the one is for the numbers and the other one is for the channels.

I want to split the numbers like this:

```
101
102
103
105
106
107
```

And I want to split the channels:

```
ABC FAMILY
CBS
CNN USA
ESPN USA
Fox News
Animal Planet
```

Here is the PHP

```
<?php
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
$errmsg_arr = array();
$errflag = false;
$link;
include ('simple_html_dom.php');
$xml = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>";
$xml = '<tv generator-info-name="www.mysite.com/test">';
$base1 = "http://www.mysite.com/get-listing.php";
$html = file_get_html($base1);      

foreach($html->find('p[id=channels]') as $element)
{
   echo $xml;
   echo $element;
}
?>
```

Can you tell me how I can split the contents I want to allow me to use two different variables as the one is for the numbers and the other one is for the channels?

Comment: php has a powerful tool called "regexp" or regular expressions. This is a great tutorial site: http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: @RobP I don't know how to use it with regexp, so how about if i should use PHP explode?

Comment: explode may do what you want but it will be less tolerant of possible errors and will break at every space so "103 CNN USA" will become ["103", "CNN", "USA"]. You just want to break into a set of digits followed by a space followed by whatever string is left, regexp will do that much more cleanly. You *need* to learn regexp to build these kinds of applications!

Comment: @RobP sorry it was my mistake. I want to split the href link to get the channel name and the id. e.g: http://www.mysite.com/get-listing.php?channels=ABC%20FAMILY&id=101 so i would get ABC FAMILY and 101.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach($html->find('p[id=channels]') as $element)
{
    $channelstr = $element->innertext;
    preg_match('/(\d+) (.*)/', $channelstr, $matches);
    echo $matches[1];
    echo $matches[2];
}
```